# What version of Clang does Visual Studio 2019 16.1.3 come with?

Tags: visual-studio, clang

I've been trying to find out so I can determine what clang-format options are supported or not.

However, I cannot find the clang executable anywhere, it is not in the same location in the Community edition as it is on Professional, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The main executable is called `clang-cl.exe`.

In my Visual Studio 2019 (latest version) I can find executables for `clang*.exe`
inside the folders:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin`

You will find more information in the following Microsoft articles:

- [Clang/LLVM Support in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/)
- [Clang/LLVM support in Visual Studio projects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-msbuild?view=vs-2019)

Comment: There is no ```llvm``` folder inside the ```tools``` folder. The only folder inside is ```MSVC```. (At least for me)

Comment: Read the two articles for the required conditions.